# Degree of a polynomial injective on complex upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

> Any polynomial function injective on the upper half plane has degree less than or equal to 2.

This seems intuitively true, since polynomial of degree $n$ will approximately be an $n$ fold covering map. However I have no idea how to prove it explictely. I tried to show that polynomial of degree > 2 is not injective by finding two points having the same value, but it didn't work well. Any idea for this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $P$ is a degree $3$ or higher polynomial; wlog we can assume $P$ monic since dividing by a non zero constant doesn't change injectivity, so $P(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ and in particular there is $R_P>0$ st for $|z| \ge R_P$ we have $|z^n| >|P(z)-z^n|$

Now since $n \ge 3$ the equation $z^n=e^{in\pi/4}$ has at least two roots $e^{\pi i/4}, e^{\pi i/4+2\pi i/n}$ in the upper half plane since $1/4+2/n \le 1/4+2/3 <1$ and let those two roots be $e^{i\alpha}, e^{i\beta}$ with $\sin \alpha, \sin \beta >\delta >0$ fixed.

Hence if we consider the rectangle $G$ bounded by $x= \pm 2R, y=R\delta, y=2R$ where we take $R \delta >R_P$, then $R \sin \alpha >R\delta, R\sin \alpha < 2R$ and same for $R \sin \beta$ while clearly $|R \cos \alpha| <2R, |R \cos \beta| <2R$, so both $Re^{i\alpha}, Re^{i\beta}$ are inside $G$; but we have that $|P(z)-z^n| <|z|^n$ on the boundary of $G$ since $w \in \bar G$ implies $|w|>R_P$ by our choices as $\Im w \ge R \delta >R_P$

Hence by Rouche $P(z)=R^ne^{in\pi/4}$ and $z^n=R^ne^{in\pi/4}$ have same number of roots in $G$, while the latter equation has at least the two roots $Re^{i\alpha}, Re^{i\beta}$, so $P$ cannot be injective in $G$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
 p(z) = z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0
$$
be a monic polynomial of degree $n \ge 3$. We want to show that $p$ is not injective in the upper half-plane.

(The *idea* is that $p(z) \sim z^n$ for sufficiently large $z$, so that $p$ takes the same values at points which roughly differ by an argument of $2\pi/n$, and some large values must be taken twice in the upper half-plane.)

The function
$$
 f(z) = \frac{1}{p(1/z)} = \frac{z^n}{1 + a_{n-1}z + \ldots + a_0z^n}
$$
is holomorphic in a sufficiently small disk $B_r(0)$, with an $n$-fold zero at the origin. It follows that
$$
 f(z) = h(z)^n
$$
where $h$ is holomorphic and injective in $B_r(0)$ with $h(0) = 0$ and $h'(0) = 1$. The preimage of a small segment $(-i \epsilon, 0)$ on the negative imaginary axis are $n$ curves $\gamma_k$, emanating from the origin with an argument of
$$
 \alpha_k = -\frac{\pi}{2n} - k \frac{2 \pi}{n}, \, k = 0, \ldots, n-1 \, .
$$
Since $n \ge 3$, both $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$ are in the range $(-\pi, 0)$, so that the initial parts of both $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ are in the lower half-plane.

So $f$ takes values on the segment $(-i \epsilon, 0)$ at least twice in the lower half-plane, which means that $p$ takes some values at least twice in the upper half-plane.

This shows that a polynomial of degree $\ge 3$ can not be injective in the upper half-plane.